# I cannot install TeeChart2013 for Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, windows-7-x64, teechart

I cannot install TeeChart2013 for Delphi 7. 
I did the following: 
1. All the *tee* files were deleted from the Windows folder and its sub-folders.
2. All the *tee* files were deleted from the Borland\Delphi folder and its sub-folders.
3. The TChart component disappeared from the Delphi component library.

Then I installed the TeeChart2013Delphi7.exe file, a trial version downloaded from the official web site.
The installation went successfully and the component library displayed a new tab with the TeeChart components.
After that, I created a new project, added TChart on an empty form, and compiled the project.
The following error displayed:

[image]

Then I added the TeeGDTPlus component on the form and specified the above Chart in its properties. I switched Active to true and then to false. 
After that, I removed TeeGDTPlus from the form and its unit was deleted from the project’s  “uses”. The project compiled successfully but when the application run the following error displayed:

[image]

The same error was displayed in my other project which used the old version of TChart.

*"Error reading Chart.Legend.Shadow.Color: Property Shadow does not exist"*

When I install the 8th version of TeeChart it causes to the same results when I am running the project’s executable file:

*"Error reading Chart.ColorPaletteIndex: Property ColorPaletteIndex does not exist"*

I suggest that the old default Delphi 7’s TChart version still exists somewhere in dcu or bpl files.

Please help me to achieve the correct TeeChart2013’s operation in Delphi 7.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I suggest that the old default Delphi 7’s TChart version still exists
>   somewhere in dcu or bpl files.

Yes, this looks like to be the case. Please go to *Tools -> Environment options -> Library -> Library path* and make sure that the new TeeChart version paths are **on top** of the list so they are the first used by the IDE. Also do the same at *Project -> Options -> Directories/Conditionals -> Search path* and enable the *Default* checkbox.

Comment: Thank you! Now everything is OK :)